# Как открыть только нужного потомка?

Tags: javascript

Для примера сделал вот такую вёрстку

```js
document.getElementById("bth").onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector(".item-trigger").classList.toggle("item-trigger-h");
}
```

```css
.items {
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ccc, #fbfbfb);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.item:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #fbfbfb);
}

.item-trigger {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.item-trigger-h {
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #ccc, #fbfbfb);
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px
}

.flex {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="items">
    <div id="bth" class="item">
      Тут очевидно заголовок при клике на который мы будем открывать/закрывать блок с основной статьёй
    </div>
    <div class="item-trigger">
      А вот тут уже статья и можно с картинкой или вообще не важно с какой информацией лиж бы это всё стилизовать в css
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente error sint voluptates fugit cum consequuntur fuga voluptatibus, repellat modi itaque!
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="items">
    <div id="bth1" class="item">
      Тут очевидно заголовок при клике на который мы будем открывать/закрывать блок с основной статьёй
    </div>
    <div class="item-trigger">
      А вот тут уже статья и можно с картинкой или вообще не важно с какой информацией лиж бы это всё стилизовать в css
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente error sint voluptates fugit cum consequuntur fuga voluptatibus, repellat modi itaque!
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Как видим в примере блока два но псевдо кнопки имеют разный ID но писать для каждого ID свой **onclick** ни есть good.

И от туда вопрос..

Как открыть только тот блок который внутри нужного родителя ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".items .item").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    this.parentNode.querySelector(".item-trigger").classList.toggle("item-trigger-h");
  });
});
```